# bitnami parse server upgrade issue

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, bitnami

I am trying to upgrade the AWS parse server using instructions in the link from bitnami. I created the EC2 instance using bitnami-ami on AWS.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/parse/administration/upgrade/

I am getting the following error:

```
:/opt/bitnami/parse# npm install parse-server parse-dashboard
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "parse-server" under a package
npm ERR! also called "parse-server". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For more information, see:
npm ERR!     <https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-24T10_33_39_499Z-debug.log
```

The error is strange as an upgrade does mean that the existing folder would be replaced. So what does this exactly mean '**Refusing to install package with name "parse-server" under a package
also called "parse-server"**'

I am running command with sudo, so permission is not an issue.

********ctlscript status******************************************
Though it is not exactly related to the above issue, but I am putting here in case someone faced this issue. My status is not coming correctly. Script shows that everything is down, when in fact everything is up and I am able to login.

```
/opt/bitnami# ./ctlscript.sh status
mongodb not running
apache not running
parse-dashboard not running
parse not running
```

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. We asked for more information to investigate the issue [here](https://community.bitnami.com/t/bitnami-parse-server-upgrade-issue-on-aws/82464). Can you provide the Bitnami Parse version you launched so we can work on reproducing the issue?